# Use of csv.DictReader in Python to create a dictionary in memory where heading are keys and colums are lists

Tags: python, csv

What is an elegant way to use csv.DictReader to  create a dictionary in memory where the headers of the csv file are keys, and the columns are lists. domething like:

So, if the csv file is as follows:

```
key1  key2  key3
   1     6     9
   2     7    10
   3     8    11
```

The resulting dictionary will be:

```
{'key1': [1,2,3],'key2': [6, 7, 8], 'key3': [9, 10, 11]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data format is not one that is easily parsed by `csv`. You could, however, just split the lines yourself:

```
with open(filename,'r') as f:
    keys=next(f).split()
    data=[row.split() for row in f]
    columns=map(list,zip(*data))
    result=dict(zip(keys,columns))
```

Comment: Actually I checked this code but doesn't work: checking with a file as described I get {'Col1': ['1,2,3', '4,5,6', '7,8,9', 'foo,']} instead of: {'Col1': ['1,2,3'], 'Col2': ['4,5,6'],... etcetera.

Comment: Your original post implies there are no commas between the entries, but your comment implies there are... [ideone](http://ideone.com/gwqBi)

Comment: Oh, yes! Sorry about that: this code works exactly as I needed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d=defaultdict(list)
for line in reader:
    for key, value in line.items():
        d[key].append(value)
```